# How to map DesiredAccess in NtCreateFile/NtOpenFile API calls?

Tags: windows, file-io, msdn

I have a system wherein I get DesiredAccess for NtCreateFile/NtOpenFile in hex format and I am supposed to map it to actual flags of read/write operations.

I came across this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441672.aspx
But the codes seem old and do not match to the ones I get.

I am new to msdn api calls. Can you please suggest how I may do it?

Comment: Which flags do you expected and which flags do you get? Show some code, please.

Comment: I get something like 0xc00010d0 and I have to map it to data structure that has keys for FILE_READ_ACCESS, FILE_WRITE_ACCESS etc.. It's like what is mentioned in the link I pasted above. But I need correct mapping, which I'm not being able to find.

Comment: You get bitmask of the flags, where is your problem?

Comment: Download the Windows SDK and look at the relevant header files.

Comment: Thanks @Xearinox. I finally figured it out.